# Rewrite summation formula to MatLab

Tags: matlab

I have a following formula:

[image]

and I need it to rewrite it to MatLab. The problem is, I'm not very experienced with it, so I'm not sure, if this is the right way to do it.

My code looks like this:

```
f = @(alpha, beta, gamma, delta)...
       alpha*sum((DOF.^(2*beta)) .* log(DOF))...
       + gamma*sum( (DOF.^(beta+delta) .* log(DOF))./nprocs )
```

`DOF` and `nprocs` are vectors of numbers with `n` elements.

Is it ok or is there some mistake in my code? I'm not sure about the summation of i-th members especially, I'm quite confused by those vector multiplications etc.

Comment: IS there anything that makes you thing your code is not OK?

Comment: @AnderBiguri There is, I'm trying to find a mistake in my code and I was suspicious, that I've written some functions incorrectly. I'll ask about the whole problem in the other question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks good.

You do not need `.^` - you can just use `^`, 
assuming `beta,delta` etc are scalar.

I should mention that the variable `DOF` and `nprocs` may be treated as a "closure" - i.e. will be incorporated from the scope in which the function is defined. If you want to avoid this, `DOF` and `nprocs` should be included as a parameter.